# How to include my own(non-moduled) scripts using Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm using browserify to use modules .

I have a JS file that is *not* a CommonJS module (not using exports/module).

> **`File3.js`**:

```
var scr = require('./utils/scripts.js');
scr.go(555); // note there is no `module.exports` here
```

Where **`scripts.js`**

```
function go(a)
{
 console.log("go:"+a);
}
```

So now I'm adding 'file3.js' to my gulp file :

```
 // main.js and main2.js are CommonJS modules and without file3 it works
 entries: ['./client/app/file3.js','./client/app/main.js', './client/app/main2.js'],
```

*(Building : .....success)*

But now when I run the page  , I get an error :

[image]

How can I include "regular" JS files with Browserify? *( not looking for a solution involving adding it directly into index.html)*

Comment: @rmjoia Thanks. I already saw that but the solution was to "modulify" the file. And I wanted to know if I can just inject that file to browserify  , without module.

Comment: I was reading this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118749/how-to-include-non-node-modules-using-browserify Option 1 or 2 .. did you read it? does it help?

this line => "app.get('/js/main.js', browserify('./client/main.js'));"

Comment: 1. edit `scripts.js` to expose your function to the global object (i.e. `window`)
2. If your have no strict limitation to use Browserify, you may look to Webpack's loader [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader) able to run the script in global context on load. his will make function `go()` accessible as `window` property. <br/>
3) Implement own Browserify transform similar to Webpack's `script-loader`.